# How to use mesos master url in a self-contained Scala Spark program

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I am creating a self-contained Scala program that uses Spark for parallelization in some parts. In my specific situation, the Spark cluster is available through mesos.

I create spark context like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("mesos://zk://<mesos-url1>,<mesos-url2>/spark/mesos-rtspark").setAppName("foo")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

I found out from searching around that you have to specify MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY env var to point to the libmesos library, so when running my Scala program I do this:

```
MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.dylib sbt run
```

But, this results in a SparkException:

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'mesos://zk://<mesos-url1>,<mesos-url2>/spark/mesos-rtspark'
```

At the same time, using spark-submit seems to work fine after exporting the MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY env var.

```
MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.dylib spark-submit --class <MAIN CLASS> ./target/scala-2.10/<APP_JAR>.jar
```

Why?

How can I make the standalone program run like spark-submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [spark-mesos](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspark-mesos) jar to your classpath.